# Removing an extra "" from an array

Tags: javascript

I'm going to re-write a simple neural network at the command line so I don't run into NPM bullshit from here on out!

The problem is an extra "" gets added to the array. I refuse to write a regex for personal reasons. Let's just say it's unimportant. Let us proceed...

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function() {

    var trainingSet = "001111101011",
    neuralNetworkStrength = 3;

    var neuralNetwork = []; 

    // e)ssential for loop
    for (var e = 0; e <= (trainingSet.length / neuralNetworkStrength); e++){

        neuralNetwork[e]= trainingSet.substr(e*neuralNetworkStrength,neuralNetworkStrength);

    }


    console.log(neuralNetwork); // [ '001', '111', '101', '011', '' ]



}); // I will eventually remove gulp so I own rights to the code.
```

Comment: "I refuse to write a regex for personal reasons." - did a nasty regular-expression hurt you as a child?

Comment: You can use Array.prototype.filter to filter out empty string

Comment: *" I refuse to write a regex for personal reasons"* - Allergies?

Comment: Who the hell down-voted thangngoc89!? He wrote it out first, solved it, I thanked him, and someone voted it down! People! Jesus Christ! Is it worth more to you that you're the high scorer? When someone deserves an upvote, you damn well better up vote!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your algorithm is wrong. You must use `<` operator in the loop instead of `<=` operator.

Full code:

```
var trainingSet = "001111101011",
neuralNetworkStrength = 3;

var neuralNetwork = []; 

// essential for loop
for (var e = 0; e < (trainingSet.length / neuralNetworkStrength); e++){

    neuralNetwork[e]= trainingSet.substr(e * neuralNetworkStrength,neuralNetworkStrength);

}


console.log(neuralNetwork);
```

Comment: Didn't see the `<=` *facepalm*

Comment: thangngoc89 I'm glad you found the simplest way to solve this. I would hate to have to write something with a bunch of scribbles or array.prototype at the end. Thank you.

Comment: This guy has came up with the same solution as me.  He came up with the correct way before I realized the actual issue.  I only fixed my answer after I saw his answer as I realized my answer was more complicated that it needed to be.

Comment: @thangngoc89 Don't mention it. :)

Comment: This answer would be a lot better if it actually explained what is different in that block of code, rather than leaving us to spot the subtle difference.

Comment: @nnnnnn Updated my answer

Comment: I vote we let thangngoc89 tell us in his own words since he's essentially copy+pasting TechnoCF, who wrote it clearer. I won't accept this answer without you editing it, thangngoc89.

Comment: @tylerl-uxai I updated my answer. It's hard to satisfy everyone

Comment: I'm glad it's settled!

Comment: I love how this is literally less better for the audience now that people were able to fight over how to properly address the subject... Notice how your response to us takes priority over what should be talking to new visitors! Remove the "update" as well as "there you go". Do it for some reason other than the big check mark proving you had the best solution. Now improve the site's UX a little bit. You're going to kill me for this, I know. I just have to prove a point.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the `<=` in your for loop with `<`.  That should fix your problem.

Comment: Are you sure this will cover all the cases ?

Comment: @thangngoc89 This will fix this guys problem now.  He isn't being very specific with his question.

Comment: I don't want to hurt my poor friend! How do I do it without removing something from his brain? *lightning cracks* Wa ha ha!

Comment: If the "" is always the last element, this should work fine

Comment: Fixed my answer to properly fix the issue.

Comment: TechnoCF, it's worse to know you're probably the one who down-voted thangngoc89. I guess I will let you have the green check mark until he changes the words to better serve the audience!

Comment: I had reason to believe you would choose to. Now we know! Whoever did didn't waste their precious up-vote on yours...